# В чём разница между вызовом родительского eventFilter и возвратом false в eventFilter?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В чём разница между вызовом родительского `eventFilter` и возвратом `false` в `eventFilter` в некотором классе, наследуюемом от `QDialog`?

Comment: В разных реализациях => разный результат. Самим смотреть разницу затруднено?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в документации написано, что `true` поглощает ивент, а `false` отдаёт его дальше родителю и прочим хендлерам. Вопрос в том, в чём разница между возвратом `false` и прямым вызовом родительского обработчика (родитель стандартный Qt-шный), т.к. видел, что делают и так, и так

Comment: Ну вот и ответ написали сами. Просто дочерний может вернуть и  false  и  true. Если предполагаете не отдавать дальше, то используете родительский(я не пользуюсь QT, но тут все очевидно)